# Zend 2 и запросы с использованием Zend\Db\Sql\Sql

Tags: mysql, база-данных, zend2

Здравствуйте!
Пробую получать доступ к данным из нескольких таблиц MySQL. База на Денвере. В стандартном туториале Zend2 в Album обращение строится через TableGateway, я так понимаю, что к нескольким таблицам через него не обратиться. Поэтому делаю так:

**создаю фабрику для адаптера к базе:**

`return array(
        'service_manager' =>  array(
            'factories' => array(
                'ZendDbAdapterAdapterBarcervice' => function($sm){
                    $config = $sm->get('Config');
                    return new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($config['dbconf2']);
                    },
                ),
            ),
    );`

**прописываю настройки dbconf2:**

```
return array(
'dbconf2' => array(
    'driver' => 'Pdo',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=bar_service;host=localhost',
    'driver_options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
        ),
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    ),
);
```

**в модуле прописываю метод getServiceConfig():**

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'BarcerviceModelBarcerviceSql' => function($sm){
                $sqlGateway = $sm->get('BarcerviceSQLService');
                $sql = new Model\BarcerviceSql($sqlGateway);
                return $sql;
                },
            'BarcerviceSQLService' => function($sm){
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('ZendDbAdapterAdapterBarcervice');
                return new Sql($dbAdapter);
                }
            ),
    );
}
```

**в контроллере прописываю метод getSQLGateway() получения шлюза к БД:**

```
public function getSQLGateway()
{
    if (!$this->sqlGateway){
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->sqlGateway = $sm->get('Barcervice\Model\BarcerviceSql');
        }
    return $this->sqlGateway;
}
```

**и использую его в контроллере для инициализации функционала модели:**

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->initialise();
    $answer = $this->model->getAllCableTypes();
    $form = new BarcerviceForm();
    var_dump($answer);
    return array('form' => $form);
}
```

Так вот, метод `model->getAllCableTypes()` ссылается на метод `sql->getAllCabletypes()` - в коде этого метода функционал, который должен, собственно, выполнять запросы к БД:

```
public function getAllCableTypes()
{
    $select = $this->sql->select()->from('cable_types');
    $statement = $this->sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
    $result = $statement->execute();
    return $result;
}
```

В документации написано, что метод `execute()` должен возвращать объект класса `ResultSet`, а он возвращает объект, не содержащий ничего, кроме настроек подключения:

```
object(Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet)#257 (8) {
  ["allowedReturnTypes":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=&gt;
    string(11) "arrayobject"
    [1]=&gt;
    string(5) "array"
  }
  ["arrayObjectPrototype":protected]=>
  object(ArrayObject)#248 (1) {
    ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["returnType":protected]=>
  string(11) "arrayobject"
  ["buffer":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["count":protected]=>
  int(1)
  ["dataSource":protected]=>
  object(Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result)#256 (8) {
    ["statementMode":protected]=>
    string(7) "forward"
    ["resource":protected]=>
    object(PDOStatement)#255 (1) {
      ["queryString"]=>
      string(25) "SELECT * FROM cable_types"
    }
    ["options":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["currentComplete":protected]=>
    bool(false)
    ["currentData":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["position":protected]=>
    int(-1)
    ["generatedValue":protected]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["rowCount":protected]=>
    int(1)
  }
  ["fieldCount":protected]=>
  int(3)
  ["position":protected]=>
  int(0)
}
```

**Похоже, что что-то я делаю не так...
Так как же все-таки обратиться к БД через `Zend\Db\Sql\Sql` класс?**

Answer (score 1):

```
<facepalm>

$result->current()

</facepalm>
```

И все работает.